# The sum cannot show although i click on the button

Tags: javascript, html

What I want is, after the user enters the number of subjects, the system will show the number of input box according to the number of subjects entered, then when the user clicks on the button, it should show the sum. I tried many ways, but I failed to show the sum, anyone knows what is the mistake I made?

Below is my code:

```js
function select() {

  var x = parseInt(document.getElementById('1').value);

  if (document.getElementById('1').value == "") {
    alert("Please fill up number of subject");
  } else if (isNaN(x) == true) {
    alert("Please fill up number of subject with number");
  } else {

    var subject = parseInt(document.getElementById('1').value);
    var sum = 0;

    for (var num = 1; num <= subject; num++) {

      document.write("Enter the mark for subject " + num + " : ");
      var value = parseFloat(document.write("<input/><br>"));

      sum += value;

    }

    var calc = document.write("<button>Next</button><br>");
    calc.onclick = function() {
      next()
    };

    function next() {
      document.write("Total marks: " + sum + "%");
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  Enter the number of subject: <input type="text" onkeypress="return/[0-9]/i.test(event.key)" id="1" value=""><br>
  <button onclick="select()">Check</button><br>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The `next()` function is out of scope of the added `next` button.

Comment: @Lynn if you got your answer, to forget to also up vote the answer that helped you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how I have rewritten a big part of your code. I have place inline comments to explain what I do.

```js
function select() {

  var x = parseInt(document.getElementById('1').value, 10);
  // Getting the div that wraps the initial form.
  var formWrapper = document.querySelector('.formWrapper');
  // Getting the div, that is going to display the new fields and the results.
  var results = document.querySelector('.results');

  // I have switch your statement from x == '' to '' === x as it 
  // consists a good practice
  if ( '' === x ) {
    alert("Please fill up number of subject");
  // I have remove the isNaN(x) == true, because the isNan will 
  // be either true or false.
  } else if ( isNaN(x) ) {
    alert("Please fill up number of subject with number");
  } else {
    // Using parseInt(x, 10) to set the base.
    var subject = parseInt(x, 10);
    // In this array, I store the auto-generated fields.
    var fieldsList = [];

    // Removing the first div from the DOM
    formWrapper.parentElement.removeChild(formWrapper);

    for ( var num = 1; num <= subject; num++ ) {
      // I am creating a new field
      var newField = document.createElement('input');
      // I push the field into the array I made for the fields.
      fieldsList.push(newField);
      // I append the field in the HTML
      results.appendChild(newField);

      // I create a <br> tag
      var br = document.createElement('br');
      // And I append the tag in the DOM
      results.appendChild(br);
    }

    // I create the button that is going to handle the Next functionality
    var nextButton = document.createElement('button');
    // I set the button text
    nextButton.innerText = 'Next';
    // I add an Event Listener for the click event.
    nextButton.addEventListener(
      'click',
      function() {
          // I reset the sum to 0
          var sum = 0;

          // I iterate over the fields auto-generated and saved in the array
          fieldsList.forEach(
            function(field) {
              // I get the value
              sum += parseInt(field.value, 10);
            }
          );

          // I create the field that is going to display the output
          let resultText = document.createElement('div');
          // I set the text  based on the sum
          resultText.innerText = "Total marks: " + sum + "%";

          // I append the text message to the DOM
          results.appendChild(resultText);
      }
    );

    // I append the button to the DOM
    results.appendChild(nextButton);
  }

}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="formWrapper">
    Enter the number of subject: <input type="text" onkeypress="return/[0-9]/i.test(event.key)" id="1" value=""><br>
    <button onclick="select()">Check</button><br>
  </div>
  <div class="results"></div>
</body>

</html>
```